# Custom URL to a user control within my custom module

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am building a module for dot net nuke.

It is similar to a HTML module but with some customizations. The user would add it multiple times on a page. I would like to create a hyperlink that the user can use to view the each one of the modules individually.

I want to add functionality so that a particular module can be displayed with its contents as if it were added to a page.

e.g I add the module 3 times on /News.aspx:

```
Article1
Article2
Article3
```

I would like these urls to work (without actually creating those pages(:

```
/News/Article1UniqueKey
/News/Article2UniqueKey
/News/Article3UniqueKey
```

The Unique key would be the module ID by default or a string that the user would enter in the edit page for a module.

How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved in a few ways. The most common way is using FriendlyURL provider, such as one for Ifinity's URLMaster. You can find a number of providers available, with source, at http://www.ifinity.com.au though things will change a little bit with DNN 7.1 as URLMaster is being integrated into the product, I believe the providers will just need to be recompiled against DNN 7.1 instead of older versions.